Inconsistent marketing data returned on Facebook Graph API
If I make this call to get campaign data from the Graph API:
const url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/${account}/insights?time_increment=30&time_range={since:'2024-01-01',until:'2024-01-30'}&level=campaign&fields=campaign_id,campaign_name,frequency,spend,reach,impressions,objective,optimization_goal,clicks,actions&action_breakdowns=action_type&access_token=${token}`; 

I get 219,189 as the total reach. However, if I make the same call, changing only time_increment=7
const url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/${account}/insights?time_increment=7&time_range={since:'2024-01-01',until:'2024-01-30'}&level=campaign&fields=campaign_id,campaign_name,frequency,spend,reach,impressions,objective,optimization_goal,clicks,actions&action_breakdowns=action_type&access_token=${token}`;

I get 287,141 as the total reach. If, finally, I change time_increment=1
const url = `https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/${account}/insights?time_increment=1&time_range={since:'2024-01-01',until:'2024-01-30'}&level=campaign&fields=campaign_id,campaign_name,frequency,spend,reach,impressions,objective,optimization_goal,clicks,actions&action_breakdowns=action_type&access_token=${token}`;     

I get 391,900 as total reach. As we can see, these are very inconsistent figures. What could be the cause of this Thanks in advance!
Technical detail: I'm calling the data via the GET REST API method >> const data = await fetch(url). I'm not using an SDK.
I expect to recieve the same reach figure, independently of the time_increment parameter.

Documentation says this parameter is ignored if time_range is also specified.

@C3roe, the documentation says: "(...)This param is ignored if time_ranges is specified." The thing is that I am using time_range, not time_ranges.
